# Image Target Vufroria Sample example

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia

i want to make my own object of tracker like in Image Target example i want to replace the Teapot by another 3D shape , the problem is i can't understand the code very well! here is the Code: 
Teapot Class:
have two Functions:
 setVerts() and  setIndices() with alot of indices and vertices numbers

and the ImageTargetRender is:

```
// The renderer class for the ImageTargets sample. 
public class ImageTargetRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
{
    private static final String LOGTAG = "ImageTargetRenderer";

    private SampleApplicationSession vuforiaAppSession;
    private ImageTargets mActivity;

    private Vector<Texture> mTextures;

    private int shaderProgramID;

    private int vertexHandle;

    private int normalHandle;

    private int textureCoordHandle;

    private int mvpMatrixHandle;

    private int texSampler2DHandle;

    private Teapot mTeapot;

    private float kBuildingScale = 12.0f;
    private SampleApplication3DModel mBuildingsModel;

    private Renderer mRenderer;

    boolean mIsActive = false;

    private static final float OBJECT_SCALE_FLOAT = 3.0f;


    public ImageTargetRenderer(ImageTargets activity,
        SampleApplicationSession session)
    {
        mActivity = activity;
        vuforiaAppSession = session;
    }


    // Called to draw the current frame.
    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
    {
        if (!mIsActive)
            return;

        // Call our function to render content
        renderFrame();
    }


    // Called when the surface is created or recreated.
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
    {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "GLRenderer.onSurfaceCreated");

        initRendering();

        // Call Vuforia function to (re)initialize rendering after first use
        // or after OpenGL ES context was lost (e.g. after onPause/onResume):
        vuforiaAppSession.onSurfaceCreated();
    }


    // Called when the surface changed size.
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)
    {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "GLRenderer.onSurfaceChanged");

        // Call Vuforia function to handle render surface size changes:
        vuforiaAppSession.onSurfaceChanged(width, height);
    }


    // Function for initializing the renderer.
    private void initRendering()
    {
        mTeapot = new Teapot();

        mRenderer = Renderer.getInstance();

        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, Vuforia.requiresAlpha() ? 0.0f
            : 1.0f);

        for (Texture t : mTextures)
        {
            GLES20.glGenTextures(1, t.mTextureID, 0);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, t.mTextureID[0]);
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
            GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA,
                t.mWidth, t.mHeight, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA,
                GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t.mData);
        }

        shaderProgramID = SampleUtils.createProgramFromShaderSrc(
            CubeShaders.CUBE_MESH_VERTEX_SHADER,
            CubeShaders.CUBE_MESH_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        vertexHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID,
            "vertexPosition");
        normalHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID,
            "vertexNormal");
        textureCoordHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID,
            "vertexTexCoord");
        mvpMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramID,
            "modelViewProjectionMatrix");
        texSampler2DHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramID,
            "texSampler2D");

        try
        {
            mBuildingsModel = new SampleApplication3DModel();
            mBuildingsModel.loadModel(mActivity.getResources().getAssets(),
                "ImageTargets/Buildings.txt");
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "Unable to load buildings");
        }

        // Hide the Loading Dialog
        mActivity.loadingDialogHandler
            .sendEmptyMessage(LoadingDialogHandler.HIDE_LOADING_DIALOG);

    }


    // The render function.
    private void renderFrame()
    {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        State state = mRenderer.begin();
        mRenderer.drawVideoBackground();

        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        // handle face culling, we need to detect if we are using reflection
        // to determine the direction of the culling
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
        GLES20.glCullFace(GLES20.GL_BACK);
        if (Renderer.getInstance().getVideoBackgroundConfig().getReflection() == VIDEO_BACKGROUND_REFLECTION.VIDEO_BACKGROUND_REFLECTION_ON)
            GLES20.glFrontFace(GLES20.GL_CW); // Front camera
        else
            GLES20.glFrontFace(GLES20.GL_CCW); // Back camera

        // did we find any trackables this frame?
        for (int tIdx = 0; tIdx < state.getNumTrackableResults(); tIdx++)
        {
            TrackableResult result = state.getTrackableResult(tIdx);
            Trackable trackable = result.getTrackable();
            printUserData(trackable);
            Matrix44F modelViewMatrix_Vuforia = Tool
                .convertPose2GLMatrix(result.getPose());
            float[] modelViewMatrix = modelViewMatrix_Vuforia.getData();

            int textureIndex = trackable.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("stones") ? 0
                : 1;
            textureIndex = trackable.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("tarmac") ? 2
                : textureIndex;

            // deal with the modelview and projection matrices
            float[] modelViewProjection = new float[16];

            if (!mActivity.isExtendedTrackingActive())
            {
                Matrix.translateM(modelViewMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                    OBJECT_SCALE_FLOAT);
                Matrix.scaleM(modelViewMatrix, 0, OBJECT_SCALE_FLOAT,
                    OBJECT_SCALE_FLOAT, OBJECT_SCALE_FLOAT);
            } else
            {
                Matrix.rotateM(modelViewMatrix, 0, 90.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0);
                Matrix.scaleM(modelViewMatrix, 0, kBuildingScale,
                    kBuildingScale, kBuildingScale);
            }

            Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjection, 0, vuforiaAppSession
                .getProjectionMatrix().getData(), 0, modelViewMatrix, 0);

            // activate the shader program and bind the vertex/normal/tex coords
            GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);

            if (!mActivity.isExtendedTrackingActive())
            {
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                    false, 0, mTeapot.getVertices());
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                    false, 0, mTeapot.getNormals());
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2,
                    GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mTeapot.getTexCoords());

                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

                // activate texture 0, bind it, and pass to shader
                GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
                GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    mTextures.get(textureIndex).mTextureID[0]);
                GLES20.glUniform1i(texSampler2DHandle, 0);

                // pass the model view matrix to the shader
                GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, false,
                    modelViewProjection, 0);

                // finally draw the teapot
                GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,
                    mTeapot.getNumObjectIndex(), GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
                    mTeapot.getIndices());

                // disable the enabled arrays
                GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
                GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
                GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);
            } else
            {
                GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                    false, 0, mBuildingsModel.getVertices());
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                    false, 0, mBuildingsModel.getNormals());
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2,
                    GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mBuildingsModel.getTexCoords());

                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

                GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
                GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    mTextures.get(3).mTextureID[0]);
                GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, false,
                    modelViewProjection, 0);
                GLES20.glUniform1i(texSampler2DHandle, 0);
                GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0,
                    mBuildingsModel.getNumObjectVertex());

                SampleUtils.checkGLError("Renderer DrawBuildings");
            }

            SampleUtils.checkGLError("Render Frame");

        }

        GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        mRenderer.end();
    }


    private void printUserData(Trackable trackable)
    {
        String userData = (String) trackable.getUserData();
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "UserData:Retreived User Data \"" + userData + "\"");
    }


    public void setTextures(Vector<Texture> textures)
    {
        mTextures = textures;

    }

}
```

building.xml is another file with diffrent numbers of vertices and indices 
i'm Confused about the numbers in building.xml and in setVertx() ,setindcises() 
plz help.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't define a 3d object the way teapot have been defined. 
I would use a library like [RajawaliVuforia](https://github.com/MasDennis/RajawaliVuforia), If i was you.

Comment: thanks for replaying ,i was able to replace the teapot by changing the teapot class with my own shape vertices and i followed this link  https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/replacing-teapot and it worked for me